# Can a splitter be used to stream video from a one port modem ie roku

Tags: ethernet, port, splitter

I have a time warner cable modem with one port, can I use an ethernet port splitter for the roku?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try to include more details on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Splitters are never a good idea.  Just buy a cheap home router/switch combo from your local computer store, or used from a site like Craigslist.

Comment: Switches are almost never good to connect to modems either, you usually need a router.

Comment: I made the assumption the modem was a router as well...  But, its a good point

Comment: I made the assumption that the "Ethernet port splitter" was a switch, he just did not know what to call it.

Comment: I assumed he meant an rj45 splitter...